# When to apply zero-centered data in an convolutional neural network

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am building a cnn right now to classify grayscale images. The network did train until 97% accuracy on the test set until it got stuck. 
Now i discovered that i forgot to zero-center the data before feeding it into the network. While thinking about where to best apply it i came up with more than one answer and like to have some thoughts on them.

First a small overview over my architecture: 
I am loading the datasets (train, validation, test) completely into the RAM. During runtime i load batches of images into placeholders which i then distort by randomly manipulating the brightness and contrast and then feed them into the network.

Now, when i'd like to apply zero-centering, i could either take the mean of the training dataset and subtract it from every picture i feed into the network or i could subtract the mean of every single picture by using the tf.image.per_image_standardization() method from tensorflow.

But if i calculate the mean of the training images, do i subtract it before or after i randomly distort the images? 
And also if i use the network later to label real images, do i need to save the mean value and subtract it also from every picture i want to classify?

Same goes for the per_image_standardization, do i apply it before or after distorting the images and do i also apply it on the real world data i want to classify later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Distortions should be applied before and normalisation/standardisation. The idea of distorting the training set is to simulate having more data than you actually have, so you should do everything you would do to a test example on the distorted training data. This means saving the dataset statistics if you want to use dataset-wide normalisation later for test images.

Whether you standardise based on each image individually or as an entire dataset depends on the data. If there are large variations in lighting between images that aren't important - say, a classification problem for vehicles with pictures taken under different illumination levels - I'd normalise per image. If you're looking to classify something dependent on illumination levels - e.g. daytime/nighttime, indoor/outdoor classifications - I'd do it as an entire dataset.

Comment: Okay thank you for explaining. I made intuitively the right choice, but it's always better to understand the impact of choices.